# I get an "expected" error with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a novice in programming. I keep getting this EXPECTED error.

The screenshot I attached shows where the EXPECTED error is with a red mark:

[image: Screenshot]

Index:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Part 1 : Implement jQuery Datatable in ASP.NET MVC</h2>
<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>Long Des</th>
                <th>Col Div</th>
                <th>Job Title</th>
                <th>Tenure Dec</th>
                <th>Emp Start</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<style>
    tr.even {
        background-color: #F5F5F5 !important;
    }
</style>
@* Load datatable css *@
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@* Load datatable js *@
@section Scripts{
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/home/loaddata",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                        { "data": "L_FNAME", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "COL_DIV_CODE", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "JOB_TITLE", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "TENURE_DEC_YR_MO", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "EMPT_START_DATE", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "BASE", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "YTD", "autoWidth": true }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Homecontroller.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCDatatable.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult loaddata()
        {
            using (MydatabaseEntities dc = new MydatabaseEntities())
            {
                var data = dc.Employees.OrderBy(a => a.L_FNAME).ToList();
                return Json(new {data = data}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

The problem is in the home controller. This `}` causes the EXPECTED error.

This is for a homework assignment.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to include the code and the error as text, not an image. Images are less readable for users trying to help and cannot be indexed by search engines, which makes your question useless for other people with the same problem in the future.

Comment: Try commenting out lines to make the red wiggle disappear. I don't know ASP.net but I wonder if `new {data = data}` should be `new {data => data}`?

Comment: @halfer here `new {data = data}` is proper! Its not lambda, its Anonomous class.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a couple of characters. Count the braces; notice how you have more `{` than you have `}` - if the code you've posted is exactly what you have (no copy & paste errors) then you never close the class, or the namespace scope. The error message will actually say `} expected`, which is telling you that it expected to see a `}` next, but instead it found the end of the file.

Add a `}` to end the class, and another `}` to end the namespace scope, and your code will compile.